# graph component formula and simple graph question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

i have  questions about the graphs :
the first one is seems to be easier :

1 _ is there any simple graph that its nodes are two times more than its edges ? demonstrate your Answer and if the answer is yes then demonstrate that there is unlimited number of these graphs .

the second one is the hard one i guess

2 _ if G = (V,E) is a Forrest that |V|=v,|E|=e and k is the number of connected component of G . try to find a replation (formula) which connect e , v, k to each other .

i'd be thankful if someone could help me with them .

thanks

Comment: The first one is pretty easy; start by finding an example with one edge and two vertices. For the second, do you know a formula that relates the number of edges of a tree to the number of vertices of that tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Perfect matchings work here. You can also just add vertices of degree $0$ to the graph until you satisfy this quantity. So with $K_{5}$, you have $10$ edges. So add $15$ isolated vertices to the graph and you have your bounds.

2) A forest is a collection of trees. Let $T_{1}, ..., T_{k}$ be the trees with $n_{1}, ..., n_{k}$ vertices respectively. Let $n$ be the total number of vertices in the forest. A tree has $V - 1$ edges. So each connected component has $n_{i} - 1$ edges. Thus, we have: $\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_{i} = n$ (count the vertices) and $\sum_{i=1}^{k} (n_{i} - 1) = n - \sum_{i=1}^{k} 1 = n - k$ (count the edges).